# I do not understant how I get my expected result from below table

Tags: mysql

> This is my table screen shoot

[image]

> I need result like below-

[image]

> I used below query

```
select date(added_datetime), 
   (select count(social_network) from social_user where social_network = 'FBuser') as FB, 
   (select count(social_network) from social_user where social_network = 'LIuser') as LI, 
   (select count(social_network) from social_user where social_network = 'TWuser') as TW, 
   (select count(social_network) from social_user where social_network = 'GPuser') as GP 
 from social_user group by MONTH(added_datetime)
```

> I is not getting my my expected result.
>
> Please help me
>
> Sorry for my English and I don't have enough reputation that's why I can not attached sample picture

Comment: *I is not getting my my expected result.* - what result are you expecting?

Comment: please click this link http://awesomescreenshot.com/0903tq158f

I want something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional sum

```
select
concat(date(added_datetime),MONTH(added_datetime)) as `Year_month`,
sum(social_network = 'FBuser') as FB,
sum(social_network = 'LIuser') as LI,
sum(social_network = 'TWuser') as TW,
sum(social_network = 'GPuser') as GP
from social_user 
group by concat(date(added_datetime),MONTH(added_datetime))
```

EDIT :
Instead of `group by concat(date(added_datetime),MONTH(added_datetime))`
You can use as

```
group by `Year_month`
```

Comment: I agree with solution , it will give you proper result.

Comment: If this answered your question, please say thanks by 'accepting it' (the tick down the left hand side of answer) Cheers.